# не могу улучшить алгоритм комплементарности сторон днк оригами

Tags: c#, алгоритм, биоинформатика

У меня есть алгоритм комплементарности нуклеотидов днк оригами. Но он работает только на две стороны. то есть на первую и вторую строку выводимую с помощью массива.

Есть 4 нуклеотида аденин, гуанин, тимин, цитозин. Аденин комплектуется с Тимином, Цитозин с Гуанином. В конечном счете программа должна создавать круг, квадрат и треугольником соответствую комплементарности сторон. квадрат у меня получился а вот круг с треугольником нет.

Прошу помочь, буду очень благодарен за любую помощь. 
Вот код создания квадрата

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                int[] a = { 0, 1, 0 };
                int[] b = { 2, 3, 2 };

                int  i, j, n;
                n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                int[,] mas = new int[n, 2];
                Random rand = new Random();

                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    mas[i, 0] = rand.Next(0, 4);

                }
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    {
                        if (mas[i, 0] == a[j])
                        {
                            mas[i, 1] = a[j + 1];
                        }
                        else if (mas[i, 0] == b[j])
                        {
                            mas[i, 1] = b[j + 1];
                        }

                    }
                }
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < n / 2; k++)
                    {
                        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                        {

                            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(mas[j, i]);
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < n / 2; k++)
                    {
                        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                        {

                            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(mas[j, i]);

                            }

                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                    for(i= 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(mas[i, 0]);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Если честно, то как биоинформатик/генетик не могу понять, в чём тут суть. Это учебная задача по поиску сферического коня?